# Indexing a custom Stack Class

Tags: c#, list, stack

I am currently doing some C# Unit-Testing using an Udemy Course. In this course, the current Stack class is implemented:

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class Stack<T>
    {
        public readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();
        
        public int Count => _list.Count;

        public void Push(T obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            
            _list.Add(obj);
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            if (_list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            var result = _list[_list.Count - 1];
            _list.RemoveAt(_list.Count - 1);

            return result; 
        }


        public T Peek()
        {
            if (_list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return _list[_list.Count - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I do not understand why the `Peek` function can use:

```
return _list[_list.Count - 1];
```

As far as I know, a list object cannot be indexed, if such functionality is not explicitly implemented (which does not seem to be the case here). Furthermore, if I create an instance of that object:

```
Stack<int> newStack = new Stack<int>();
newStack.Push(5);
var lastElement = newStack[0];
```

I get a squiggly error message:

```
cannot apply indexing with to an expression of 'Testing.Stack<int>'
```

...which supports my assumption that this instance cannot be indexed. Can someone please explain me this behavior?

Comment: list can be indexed - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-6.0 (its implemented as a dynamic array, its not a linked list)

Comment: _list in the above code is of type `List<T>` and list does allow indexing.  [Indexing Reference for List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-item(system-int32))

Comment: the second error is because you did not implement the [] operator on your stack, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: just becasue you class has a list as part of its implementation does not mean that it supports indexing, you have to write the indexer method

Comment: you aren't trying to access the list, you are accessing the instance of Stack<T>.  You could say `newStack._list[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, A List object cannot be indexed

This is incorrect. A c# list is a type of [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), similar to the c++ `std::vector`. You are probably thinking of [*linked list*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-6.0), a completely different type, and one I would rarely recommend using.

> cannot apply indexing with to an expression of 'Testing.Stack'

This is because you have not implemented an [indexer](https://cannot%20apply%20indexing%20with%20to%20an%20expression%20of%20%27Testing.Stack%3Cint%3E%27). Assuming you want zero to be the most recently added item:

```
public T this[int i] => _list[Count  - i - 1];
```

While writing your own stack can be useful as an exercise, for real work I would recommend using the built in [stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-6.0). There is also [source code available](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs).